# 'Vue' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead

Tags: vue.js, tsx, umd

```
'Vue' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

when I try to use vue + tsx to develop a table component, I meet this question.There is a version to solve react + tsx, but it's not suit for vue.

Please help me or give me some advice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this error it was caused by a mistyped import.

```
import 'vue'
```

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```